# How to calculate the spectral irradiance of an array of LEDs?

Tags: led, infrared

Good morning, how can I calculate this equation?

[image]

The LEDs have the following specifications:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/143/EAILP05RDDB1-708504.pdf

_ 12 LEDs; 3 second exposure; 20cm distance

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There is enough information in that datasheet to make a rough estimate - spectral irradiance, wavelength graph, angle Vs magnitude.  BUT measurement and comparison to datasheet max vale at say 0 degrees would be easier and probably more accurate.

Comment: These are a PITA. 180 mW * efficacy / 0.5 sq.m (30deg @ 100mA @ 20 cm) = if an ideal LED = 0.00036 kW/m2. Vs.  spec of  18 kW/m2 * 0.44... what U think? But centre is 2x as bright intensity 30 deg area edge but includes 95% of power used by Eir equation.

Comment: then x 12 LEDs  and ? efficacy gives result.. just don't try it at 5cm distance from eyeball.  Opthmalogists use IR LED's to view the back of the eye briefly.

Comment: just don't pretend to be an opthmalogist and view the back of the eye but OK for retina fiducial biometric scanning

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for your comments. What I understand from the equation is: _ I have the bandwidth value: 45nm _ I have the value of t: 3 seconds But how could you get the spectral irradiance? Could you tell me the formula and how to solve it? Likewise, the sum of 780 to 3000, what does that refer to? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for your comments. What I understand from the equation is: _ I have the bandwidth value: 45nm _ I have the value of t: 3 seconds But how could you get the spectral irradiance? Could you tell me the formula and how to solve it? Likewise, the sum of 780 to 3000, what does that refer to? Thank you very much.

Comment: This formula shows LED is a million times weaker than heat for damaging the clear part of the eye from thermal damage yet not the spot damage for the back of the eye

Comment: 1st eyes can get cloudy from IR heat, LEDs not, but for focused spot be careful then it becomes an issue of candella and distance to. Urn spots in your image sensor , the retina

Comment: Long term it is cataract damage, worse is cancer

Comment: I had Nichia do an evaluation on some high efficiency 70 mA white (~+ 5000 degrees K) LEDs with about a  90 degree cone angle. About 130-150 lumen/Watt. Results fell in several regulatory wavelength bands. They reported that in the shortest wavelength ('deep blue') they fell in the less than 100% safe category. To my surprise.

Comment: @LuisEduardoMamaniBedregal You need to be more familiar with the requirement than you are so far to do the measurements competently yourself. While you could ;learn, if this is for a volume product the LED manufacturer may be able to help at no cost. | On page 4 of the datasheet it shows in 2nd graph spectrum from 700-1050 nm - the rest of the 780-3000 range presumably has no energy in it. In the 4th graph you see the relative energy distribution with angle.
You can use this to calculate the energy in a number of angle slices. Clearly 0 degrees in the highest output.

Comment: You need to decide the angle slices that allow you to meet the requirement. It MAY be that just summing all energy is enough.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 
Please, could you provide me with a random example of how to solve the formula in question? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Please, could you provide me with a random example of how to solve the formula in question? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Luis consider 70mW/sr x 12 LEDs on surface of 20cm range with area = trig. can you do Gr XII math in Trig?   , your talking 840mW in less than 1 square meter area and spec is 18,000 watts per square meter... no comparison, White LEDs on the other hand are unsafe with Blue content on eye retina and Gallery paintings so they use warm Xenon lights